# Preserve linebreaks - PHP variable

Tags: php

Easiest way to explain this is like this.

```
$find = "Hello
this is a new line";

$replace = "More content
Hello
this is a new line
this is an even newer line";

if(strpos($replace, $find) !== false) {
   //We have a match
}
```

If I use `strpos` it ignores the line breaks meaning it does not find a match in replace when in fact line 2 and 3 match `$find`. Is there any way around this?

The `$find` and `$replace` will need to be dynamic by using a function. I have tried `str_replace` which also does not find matches. It actually outputs `$find` as `Hello this is a new line`. It removes the linebreak and replaces it for a space.

Comment: Works fine for me! Please show us your current output and your expected one

Comment: I jsut copy pasted your example code and run it. The strpos test says there is a match. (ie putting a print in the if block works) - I wonder, if your REAL strings have different line endings, eg linux vs windows.

Comment: I tried that mate but i think it is the fact that php dont preserve linebreaks in variables. They just get ignored. I am sure there must be a way to tell a variable to preserve the linebreaks but i have not found it yet haha!

Comment: [The code you posted works in any version of PHP and HHVM](http://3v4l.org/pSavn) - your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Not true, line breaks **are** preserved in variables. Lots of things would break, if not. End of the world stuff

Comment: Problem is i am pulling content to replace with from my database into an array. So i think somewhere between the sql and the array i am losing the linebreaks. Although when i use <pre> it shows breaks in the output. I am so confused lol.

Comment: Can you `var_dump(urlencode($var))` 2 times? One where `$var` is what you get from the DB and one where it's what you're searching for. Then post it in the OP or look at the difference yourself. What's the *actual* strings?

Comment: Ok, so your problem is outside the code you posted. Fix that code.

Comment: Basically i am pulling php code from a database, opening a php file, searching for an old function to replace it with an up to date one. I wish to do this without opening the php file and doing it directly as it is not an option for the app i am making.

Comment: You are comparing characters. A line break is just another character. It might "look" different, but other than that it's another character. Hence your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: strpos wont work anyway as it only looks for part of the phrase, not an exact match. I have checked everything is coming over correctly and it does. I used <pre> on both find and match and they output the same but apparently do not match with preg_match or strpos... :/

Comment: can you update your question using the actual code you use and 1 case of the actual values you get and the actual values you expect. thanks

Comment: Works for me.  `var_dump (strpos($replace, $find));` int(13)

Comment: To explain this a little more clearly. When you "echo $find;" it outputs "Hello this is a new line". That is how the functions are also looking at it for $find. So $replace don't match as $find does not have it's linebreaks took into consideration. It would be like saying strpos("Hello\nthis is a new line', 'Hello this is a new line')

Which of course does not match because $find does not have \n in it as it is ignored...

Comment: There are different encodings for newline.  Windows uses \r\n whereas most other systems use just \n.  They look the same but they're not going to match up in a simple comparison (such as strpos does).

Comment: So there is no way of doing this Gordon? I am basically trying to dynamically update a php file script using find "nippet of code"(exact match) and replace with "new snippet of code" preserving line breaks so the files dont end up ugly...

Comment: @Martin Normalise your data and replace both \r\n, \n\r and \r with \n in both of your strings before comparison. Even better, make sure you always use a single type of newline in your data.

Comment: ..in code: `$var = preg_replace('~(\r\n|\n\r|\r)~', "\n", $var)`. Please note the double quotes around `\n` to make sure that it's being parsed as a newline, and not as a backslash followed by an "n".

Comment: what h2ooooooo said was what i eventually did and it worked :)